# Several second freezes... Is my GPU dying or is it something else?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, freeze, gpu

So i've downloaded the latest AMD driver for AMD RX 460(Adrenalin 19.12.2.) and since then I've noticed several second long freezes in games like League of Legends and Heroes of Might and Magic V. CS:GO has no problems whatsoever.
I've tried downgrading the driver and updating it again since downgrading didn't help either.
Could my GPU be dying?
When i stress-test my GPU I see no freezes in FurMark.

[GPU-Z at the same time of freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxGtz.gif)

Comment: Try a different PCIe slot if you have another one available. It's a bit weird that it's only happening on a few games though.

Comment: I'll try that. It might also be the PSU?

Comment: I don't think it's the PSU at the moment. I've had a similar problem before, but it would happen with any game just at different times. More graphically intense games crashed or freeze faster. The problem was the PCIe slot. It took me a two weeks to figure it out.

Comment: I have changed the PCI slot and the problem persists. Also it appears that the CPU Clock drops to 1550MHz  at the time of the freeze. I believe my graphics settings reset to default after changing PCI slot and now the freeze is a bit longer and more often(the same happend first time i updated my driver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was HDD actually. Trying Homm V on another disk made it lag free. CSGO had no lag and it was also on another disk. The HDD is probably dying cause it has bad sectors and now lag.